# How to declare constants

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I'm steadily getting the hang of Objective-C, but am still very much a beginner and have a beginner-level question hopefully someone could shed some light on:

If I have a very simple project and want to set a constant that I'll use throughout—say, a NSDictionary with keys being month names and values being days in that month—how is this done?  (I.e., what command form and where to put it?)

NOTE:  *If this example is already possible using built-in functions, perhaps we could just pretend it isn't for the purposes of this question ;)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer depends on the type of your constant. If all you need is an `int` or a `double`, you can use preprocessor and the `#define CONST 123` syntax. For Objective C classes, however, you need to do a lot more work.

Specifically, you would need to hide the constant behind a class method or a free-standing function. You will also need to add a prototype of that method or function in the header file, provide a function-scoped static variable to store the constant, and add code to initialize it.

Here is an example using a simple `NSDictionary`:

Header: MyConstants.h

```
@interface MyConstants
+(NSDictionary*)getConstDictionary;
@end
```

Implementation: MyConstants.m

```
+(NSDictionary*)getConstDictionary {
    static NSDictionary *inst = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        inst = @{
            @"key1": @"value1",
            @"key2": @"value2",
            @"key3": @"value3"
        };
    });
    return inst;
}
```

Usage:

```
NSString *val = [[MyConstants getConstDictionary] objectForKey:@"key2"];
```

Comment: Though, for objects that support representation as literals, the `#define` can work...strings, for example, or even: `#define REFERENCE_DICTIONARY @{@"key1": @"value1", @"key2": @"value2"}`.  The question would be how often it's evaluated vs. the setup overhead of the singleton.

Comment: @PhillipMills That's certainly true. However, I avoided suggesting it because of the gross inefficiency of this approach :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and example.  What would you say is the advantage of this approach over the extern/const answer?

Comment: @Rogare If you use `extern`, you need to call an initializing function at some point, unless the initialization can be performed without using any code (which wouldn't work for `NSDictionary`). The `dispatch_once` approach is very common and instantly recognizable, and it leaves no doubt as to when/from where the initialization takes place.

Comment: OK, I see.  So, for C primitives `#define` works, for Obj-C classes that don't require initialization function I can use `extern` and `const`, and for Obj-C classes that do require initializing (like my NSDictionary), the `dispatch_once` approach is the way to go.  Thanks, very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is correct, **but** if you prefer operate with variable (not trough method). I can suggest this pattern:

```
@implementation MyClass
 
static NSSet *mySetOfObjects;
 
+ (void)initialize {
    mySetOfObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
}

// Example usage:  
+ (BOOL)isRecognizedString:(NSString *)searchItem {
    return [mySetOfObjects containsObject:searchItem];
}
 
@end
```

As for me - it looks better.

---

For more details the [source is here](http://littlehales.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/objective-c-class-level-properties-how-to-declare-them-and-how-to-initialize-them/).

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you want to declare an NSString constant in your class that holds a url. In your header .h file you will need the following:

```
#import 

extern NSString * const BaseURL;

@interface ClassName : NSObject {
```

You will then need to set it's value in your main .m file as follows:

```
#import "ClassName.h"

NSString * const BaseURL = @"http://some.url.com/path/";

@implementation ClassName
```

You can now access this constant throughout your class or subclasses. Here's an example of usage:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BaseURL, @"filename.html"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your constants are strings then you can use this form:

MyObject.h:

```
extern NSString *const kJanuary;
....
extern NSString *const kDecember;

@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    ...
}

@end
```

MyObject.m:

```
NSString *const kJanuary = @"January";
....
NSString *const kDecember = @"December";

@implementation MyObject

....

@end
```

You can then use the constant `kJanuary`, for example, from anywhere when using your class.